# Can I put freeing system resources in finalizer in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, static

I am doing Win API calls in my program and some of them assumes need to free resources. Can I put such freeing into finalizer and be sure it will be called?

Here is how I am doing now in static methods:

```
class KeyboardListener
    {

        static KeyboardListener() {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
            Install(keyboardHook);
        }

        static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Uninstall();
        }



        static void Install(KeyboardHookDelegate proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                keyboardHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        static void Uninstall()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHookID);
        }
```

Now I want to rewrite it to non-static and wishing to decide, where to put `Uninstall` call.

Comment: as side note - call to `SetWindowsHookEx` must look like `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,  0, 0);`  not need use `GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName)` - the LL hook always called in current process - not injected. so not need dll handle

Comment: Will it listen keys globally this way?

Comment: of course yes. i even doubt that your handler in dll - otherwise pass it address have no sense at all (only dll can be injected to another process). but LL hook never injected by design. so you and not need  locate it in dll and pass it hmod

Comment: Doesn't sound like this question has anything to do with hooks. Sounds like you want to know when finalizers execute.

Comment: There is no such thing as a local low-level (keyboard) hook. Low-level hooks run, before the system has even determined, which thread ultimately receives that input. It sounds like you are using a tool you haven't fully understood, and you may just be using the wrong tool altogether.

Comment: **And be sure it will be called?** - yes. **When?** - no, see [here] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors).

Comment: @IInspectable I am writing keyboard switcher

Comment: What's keeping you from [registering a hotkey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) then?

Comment: I think it should be more smart than this.

Comment: Program is written: https://github.com/dims12/NormalKeyboardSwitcher